# img:content css issue in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, image

I have created a css class for  like this:

```
.nav-right-EmployeeEmail {
content: url('../app_resources/nav-blue-email60.png');
padding-top:5px;
width:60px;
}
```

and using it in aspx file like this:

```
<img class="nav-right-EmployeeEmail" alt="FT Logo" /></a> <a target="_self" href="index.aspx" title="Help Desk">
```

I did this to make sure if the images/logos changes in future, then I only need to change it in css file and it will be reflected on every page.

The issue is that the images are not being shown in IE9. I can only see the image placeholders but not the actual image. Please note that the `<img>` is inside an `<a>` tag.
Any help will be highly appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: can you show us some of your code ore create a jsfiddle for demo

Comment: Is it working in a modern browser or did you only test in IE9?

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and Mozilla, working fine in both. But not in IE

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sure that you need to change CSS only if the image is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is define your logo left to some element, do it like this :

```
.nav-right-EmployeeEmail:before {
    content: url(../app_resources/nav-blue-email60.png);
    padding-top:5px;
    width:60px;
}
```

And create your element like this for exemple :

```
<a class=nav-right-EmployeeEmail target="_self" href="index.aspx" title="Help Desk">some link</a>
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/UP88d/

Comment: not always `:before` is handy as user may want to run the site in older browser

Comment: If you are concerned about older browsers you should do something else since `content` is only supported by the latest browsers (especially when it comes to setting content to an image). If you are running the page on PHP, use a variable to set the URL of the image instead. Or the same with Javascript if that is your poision.

Comment: I am not sure if I explained it well. The issue, i think, is the content tag. I want to know any other way to display an image from css (obviously without using backgroun-iamge property), so that it correctly displays in IE 9. And thank you for your inputs.